# How to see my programs stack trace?

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg, dump, freeze

I am trying to learn WinDbg. In simple program, I am waiting infinitely on `Critical Section`. My program is hang, and I get dump of program using *Task Manager*.

Now, whenever I take stack trace using `kc` or `k` command, it is giving me follwoing stack trace.

```
wow64cpu!CpupSyscallStub
wow64cpu!Thunk0ArgReloadState
wow64!RunCpuSimulation
wow64!Wow64LdrpInitialize
ntdll!LdrpInitializeProcess
ntdll!_LdrpInitialize
ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk
```

Now, why is it not showing my actual code's stack trace. How I understand where exactly my program is hang?

Comment: Perhaps you are dumping the wrong thread's stack? Have you tried `~*k`?

Comment: capture the dmp with ProcessExplorer and run **!analyze -v -hang** in Windbg

Comment: If you use the 64-bit version of Task Manager to generate the dump, you will get a dump of the 32-bit emulator (wow64*). Use the 32-bit version of Task Manager to generate the crash dump of your 32-bit process.

Comment: @joshpoley ProcessExplorer generates the dumps with the correct bitness, so you don't need to care about this.

Comment: @magicandre1981 It worked to use -hang. Thanks.

Comment: @magicandre1981 OP said he used Task Manager, so I explained the deficiencies in using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to capture the dmp. Starting with version 15.13 it generates the [dumps with the correct bitness](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sysinternals/archive/2013/02/04/updates-pendmoves-v1-2-process-explorer-v15-3-sigcheck-v1-91-zoomit-v4-42.aspx).

> It also creates dump files that match the bitness of the target
>   process

Now open the dump in the Windbg.exe which fits to the bitness and run `!analyze -v -hang`

The `-hang` tells the command to do hang analysis. This should show you the part of your code where you got the hang.

Answer (score 3):

Previous answers about capturing 32 bit dumps are ok. However, if you don't have the chance to create another dump (e.g. if the problem is hard to reproduce), try the WOW64 extension:

```
0:000> k
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`0008e2e8 00000000`7449aeac wow64win!NtUserGetMessage+0xa
...
00000000`0008f7d0 00000000`00000000 ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0xe

0:000> .load wow64exts

0:000> !sw
Switched to 32bit mode

0:000:x86> k
ChildEBP RetAddr  
00141568 755f790d user32!NtUserGetMessage+0x15
00141584 004aa378 user32!GetMessageW+0x33
00141634 00400000 notepad__+0xaa378
...
```

Note how the input prompt changes to `0:000:x86>` and the callstack is displayed correctly.

While `!sw` switches forward and backward, you can also be more specific by using `.effmach x86` and `.effmach amd64`.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is a 32-bit application that runs on 64-bit Windows. You should use the 32-bit WinDbg to debug it. In a typical Windows SDK installation, it would be in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\windbg.exe`.

Comment: I am getting exactly same output with WinDbg{x86).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to world of Windbg. Unlike modern debuggers with excellent GUI, Windbg is more command line based and hence may have a steeper learning curve. But once you get a hang of it - its brilliant!

Onto your question :

Lieven has already given a hint. I'll elaborate that it a bit.

It is likely that there are more than one thread running in the sample app that you've written.

`~` will give a list of all the thread.

`~* k` will dump the stack of all the threads.

Next you can move to thread that you wish to bebug using

`~ <thread ID>s`

[This](http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html) is great resource to get started with different commands in Windbg.

Answer (score 0):

Use `!analyze -hang` or `!locks` or `¬cs -s -o -l` to see if you have a deadlock situation. The latter is the one I prefer.

As to why when you open the dump it shows an unrelated thread call stack, your program could be in the middle of anything when you create the dump, it is not always the thread of interest that is why you need to do some analysis.

From the output of `!locks` it will dump all critical sections that are locked, what you are looking for are where 2 threadId's are waiting for each other's resources, then switch to those threads using `~~[TID]s` kb to dump the call stack then look for `ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSectionfunction`, the first parameter will be the address of the critical section that it is waiting for, you should find that your 2 threads are waiting for each other's critical section. You then need to go to your code and understand if there is a flaw in your locking mechanism.

Comment: As far as I understand this is not a deadlock situation, it is a simple wait with infinite timeout.

Comment: @ThomasW. the OP mentions in the comments that `!analyze -hang` worked for him so my thought was that this was a deadlock situation